# Using sw-precache with client-side URL routes for a single page app

Tags: angularjs, service-worker, sw-precache

How would one configure sw-precache to serve `index.html` for multiple dynamic routes?

This is for an Angular app that has `index.html` as the entry point. The [current setup](https://github.com/manshar/manshar/blob/master/web-client/Gruntfile.js#L545) allows the app to be accessable offline only through `/`. So if a user go to `/articles/list/popular` as an entry point while offline they won't be able to browse it and would be given you're offline message. (although when online they'd be served the same `index.html` file on all requests as an entry point)

Can [dynamicUrlToDependencies](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#dynamicurltodependencies-objectstringarraystring) be used to do this? Or does this need to be handled by writing a separate SW script? Something like the following would do?

```
function serveIndexCacheFirst() {
  var request = new Request(INDEX_URL);
  return toolbox.cacheFirst(request);
}

toolbox.router.get(
   '(/articles/list/.+)|(/profiles/.+)(other-patterns)', 
    serveIndexCacheFirst);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `sw-precache` for this, without having to configure runtime caching via `sw-toolbox` or rolling your own solution.

The [`navigateFallback`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#navigatefallback-string) option allows you to specify a URL to be used as a "fallback" whenever you navigate to a URL that doesn't exist in the cache. It's the service worker equivalent to configuring a single entry point URL in your HTTP server, with a wildcard that routes all requests to that URL. This is obviously common with single-page apps.

There's also a [`navigateFallbackWhitelist`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#navigatefallbackwhitelist-arrayregexp) option, which allows you to restrict the `navigateFallback` behavior to navigation requests that match one or more URL patterns. It's useful if you have a small set of known routes, and only want those to trigger the navigation fallback.

There's an example of those options in use as part of the [`app-shell-demo`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/blob/master/app-shell-demo/gulpfile.babel.js#L135) that's including with `sw-precache`.

In your specific setup, you might want:

```
{
  navigateFallback: '/index.html',
  // If you know that all valid client-side routes will begin with /articles
  navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^\/articles/],
  // Additional options
}
```

Comment: jeff, i get errors using navigate fallback. I use firebase authenticate to sign in using facebook Provider. So when i click login in with facebook with navigateFallback set to index.html, lots of unexpected error come up. How do i blacklist the url for signin with facebook or other providers?

Comment: There's a whitelist, rather than a blacklist: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/blob/master/README.md#navigatefallbackwhitelist-arrayregexp

Comment: Jeff I'm rendering a 404 component any time a route(url) is enterd that is not defined in my app. <Route path='*' component = {Error404} />. using the whitelist to approve my defined routes will work but than i can't render non-defined paths in offline

Comment: There's only support for one fallback page in `sw-precache` (at least for the time being; support for "real" routing to multiple pages will hopefully come in the future). It sounds like you'll have to write some additional code and use `importScripts()` to incorporate it if you need logic beyond what `sw-precache` supports right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can use `dynamicUrlToDependencies`, as mentioned in the documentation of the `directoryIndex` option: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#directoryindex-string.