# Cache internal routes with sw-precache

Tags: caching, gulp, sw-precache

I'm creating a SPA using vanilla JavaScript and currently setting up [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) to handle the caching of resources. The service worker is generated as part of a `gulp` build and installed successfully. When I navigate to the root url (http://127.0.0.1:8080/) whilst offline the app shell displays, illustrating that resources are indeed cached.

I'm now attempting to get the SW to handle internal routing without failing. When navigating to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/dashboard_index` whilst offline I get the message 'Site can't be reached'.

The app handles this routing on the client side via a series of event listeners on the users actions or, in the case of using the back button, the url. When accessing one of these urls, no calls to the server should be made. As such, the service worker should allow these links to 'fall through' to the client side code.

I've tried a few things and expected [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597285/using-sw-precache-with-client-side-url-routes-for-a-single-page-app) to solve the problem. I've included the current state of the `generate-service-worker` gulp task, and with this setup I'd expect to be able to access `/dashboard_index` offine. Once this is working I can adapt the solution to cover other routes.

Any help much appreciated.

```
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', function(callback) {
  var  rootDir = './public';

  swPrecache.write(path.join(rootDir, 'sw.js'), {
    staticFileGlobs: [rootDir + '/*/*.{js,html,png,jpg,gif,svg}',
                      rootDir + '/*.{js,html,png,jpg,gif,json}'],
    stripPrefix: rootDir,
    navigateFallback: '/',
    navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/\/dashboard_index/],
    runtimeCaching: [{
      urlPattern: /^http:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:8080/getAllData, // Req returns all data the app needs
      handler: 'networkFirst'
    }],
    verbose: true
  }, callback);
});
```

**update**

The code to the application can be found [here](https://github.com/tonyedwardspz/social-feed-feeder).

Removing the option `navigateFallbackWhitelist` does not chage the result.

Navigating to `/dashboard_index` whilst offline prints the following to the console.

- GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/dashboard_index net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- sw.js:1 An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
- http://127.0.0.1:8080/sw.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The same `An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.` is also duplicated in the 'application > service workers' tab of chrome debug tools.

It's also noted that the `runtimeCaching` option is not caching the json response returned from that route.

Comment: Your current configuration *seems* like it should accomplish what you're trying to do. Can you confirm that you're on the latest release of `sw-precache`? Does it help if you leave out the `navigateFallbackWhitelist` option completely? It may make sense to move this to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/issues if it's a bug in `sw-precache`.

Comment: @JeffPosnick I was using an outdated version, however I get the same results after updating the package to 4.2.3.

Comment: Can you switch from `navigateFallback: '/'` to `navigateFallback: '/index.html'`? You don't have an entry for `'/'` in your list of precached resources, but you do have an entry for `'/index.html'`. There's some logic in place to automatically treat `'/'` and `'/index.html'` as being equivalent, but that doesn't apply to what `navigateFallback` is doing...

Comment: @JeffPosnick I've decided to write my own SW for this project in order to understand them better. Once I have the app working as intended, I will come back and try again. I've already found a couple of architecture decisions which prevent SW in general from working. Until then, thanks for your help, it's a great library which I am using in other projects with huge success :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, in case anyone else runs into this, I believe this answer [from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911052/cache-internal-routes-with-sw-precache#comment69091698_40911052) should address the issue:

> Can you switch from `navigateFallback: '/'` to `navigateFallback:
>   '/index.html'`? You don't have an entry for `'/'` in your list of
>   precached resources, but you do have an entry for `'/index.html'`.
>   There's some logic in place to automatically treat `'/'` and
>   `'/index.html'` as being equivalent, but that doesn't apply to what
>   `navigateFallback` is doing...

Comment: To confirm, this would of solved my problem without the underlying architecture issues.